# getWindow() not exist in Service class

Tags: android

I use this code in a service class to take screenshot in the service but `getWindow()` is not available here. what should i do?

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture

        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611568/how-to-take-save-screenshot-in-background-in-service-class-android

Comment: do you want to take screenshot in background or in forgeround?

Comment: try to use activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() or provide context to get Window

Comment: @AMIR I have added an answer, I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

Pass a reference to the activity when you create the class, and when calling relevant methods and use it. But there can be memory leaks with this approach

```
void MethodThatUsesActivity(Activity myActivityReference) {
    myActivityReference.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
}
```

Comment: I used the above code but it says : `inconvertible type: can't cast java.Security.Access.Control.Context to android.app.Activity`

Comment: no,  i used this `View v1 = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();` I don't know how to use the second method